# can't access the objects in my django app database pls help ;-;

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

The following code is what I use for my django app that I started working on. However, I am not able to access any of the objects i created independently, I know that they are present on the database as the :

```
return HttpResponse(Details.objects.all())
```

gives an output of all the data but I'm not able to access the objects with the code:

```
return HttpResponse(ID1.email)
```

help pls ;-;

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from CollectMail.models import Details
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pandas as p
import os


file = p.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Robert Chomba Mumba\Desktop\Project At Access Bank 2\Emails\test_data_final.csv")

n = len(file['EMAIL'])
j = 0
k = 1
while j != n:
    NewItem = file['EMAIL'][j]
    NewObject = 'ID' + str(k)
    NewObject = Details(email = NewItem)
    NewObject.save()
    j +=1
    k +=1
#Object names are ID1,ID2,ID3....

def index(request):
    #return HttpResponse(Details.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(ID2.email)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NewObject = 'ID' + str(k) is just creating an object of a string, you then overwrite it with the new Details() instance. Crucially, there is never an object `ID2` created. I think what you are trying to achieve could be done thus:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from CollectMail.models import Details
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pandas as p
import os


def build_objects():
    res = dict()
    file = p.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Robert Chomba Mumba\Desktop\Project At Access Bank 2\Emails\test_data_final.csv")

    n = len(file['EMAIL'])
    j = 0
    k = 1
    while j != n:
        NewItem = file['EMAIL'][j]
        NewObject = Details(email = NewItem)
        NewObject.save()
        res['ID' + str(k)] = NewObject
        j +=1
        k +=1
    return res


def index(request):
    res = build_objects()
    return HttpResponse(res['ID2'].email)
```